# Disable hover effect on topmenu using CSS

Tags: css

I tried using different codes in CSS for the right topmenu on www.skinmed.nl

my css:

```
#menu-item-3473{
pointer-events: none;
}
```

It works for disabling all events on that button, but I only want to disable the light grey color when I'm moving the mouse over it. The button has a hover image, so it needs to be working the same without the light grey color in the background.

I only want to disable the light grey hover on the social media buttons, whatsapp, facebook, instagram and newsletter. Not the buttons: ''mijn account/my account'' and ''winkelmand/shoping basket'.

Note: Thank you for replying. I tried also:

```
#access ul li:hover {
background-color: #555555 ;important!
```

and

```
#header #access ul li:hover {
background-color: #555555;
```

Note: the working code:

```
.topmenu ul li.menu-item-object-custom a:hover {
background-color: unset;
```

}

Comment: Please provide your code inside the question itself. The main requirement on stackoverflow is to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Reproduce the problem with a runnable code snippet. Inspecting your code to find out which HTML you are talking about is time consuming for us

Comment: top menu meaning the `MY ACCOUNT` `SHOPPING BASKET`??.. or the dropdown menu??

Comment: your selector is wrong you cannot have both a dot and a hash - either use a dot for a class or a hash for an id

Comment: Only the social media accounts, whatsapp, facebook, instagram and newsletter. Not the buttons: ''mijn account/my account'' and ''winkelmand/shoping basket'. '

Comment: I'm sorry but I used only the hash, I posted it wrong on stackoverflow

Comment: In that case please edit your question  and also make a [mcve] in the question itself - you cannot just paste a link to your site as that is off topic for SO: [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0):

you need to match background color on hover like this

```
#header #access ul li:hover {
    background-color: #555555;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. i tried the code with important but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

add this css. hope this helps you

```
.topmenu ul li.menu-item-object-custom a:hover {
    background-color: unset;
}
```

Comment: I can't believe it but it works! Thank you very much!